# OpenOffice неведомые текстовые поля

Tags: open-office

Понимаю что для профи вопрос покажется детским лепетом, но меня он поставил в тупик. Я только учусь, и формулировка вопроса без каких либо сносок и объяснений загоняет в ступор. Есть задание - создать таблицу в документе Writer и в ячейках сделать тестовые поля, дословно ( В ячейках где пользователь будет вводить собственные данные необходимо разместить текстовые поля).

Вставить числовое поле - ячейка С1, максимальное значение 1, по умолчанию 1, шаг значения 1.

Comment: И в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, где находится это меню для вставки текстовых полей, и числовых полей. При этом, в предварительном просмотре, данные поля выглядят утопленными.

Comment: А какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к программированию?

Comment: Ну насколько я в курсе, опен офисом пользуются прогеры и "линуксоиды", думал тут помогут.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, тогда почему в данной теме присутствуют теги по вопросам опенофисе?

Comment: Если среди них есть такие вопросы, которые не имеют прямого отношения к программированию или к системному администрированию, значит пользователи прозевали их и не закрыли во время.

Comment: Тоесть ответа на данный вопрос вы дать не можете?

Comment: @LEQADA, нет. Тут про добавление контролов форм в документ.

Comment: И я тоже [15 символов]

Comment: Ответ готов :)​

Answer (score 5):

Создание таблицы, надеюсь, проблемой не является. Покажу, как создать числовое поле.

1. Создать новый текстовый документ.
2. Включить панель элементов управления:
   [image: Вид -> Панели инструментов -> Элементы управления]
3. Нажать кнопку показа дополнительных элементов:
   [image: Дополнительные элементы управления]
4. Нажать кнопку числового поля и нарисовать его (как прямоугольник) в документе:
   [image: Числовое поле]
5. В контекстном меню открыть свойства элемента:
   [image: Элемент управления...]
6. В появившемся окне заполнить имя и требуемые поля:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Выйти из режимов разработки и выделения:
   [image: Выделить, Режим разработки]
8. Поле можно заполнять и/или менять число стрелочками вверх/вниз.